# Building a Linux Docker image on Windows 10: "exec format error"

Tags: docker, conda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using as a base, the following image: https://github.com/Kaggle/docker-python/blob/main/Dockerfile.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM kaggle/python
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"]
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "--login", "-c" ]
RUN ["/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/bin/env" ]
RUN ["exec '$@'"]
RUN ["bash"]
```

I am running the command: `docker build -t kaggle/no-jupyter .`

At line 4 I get the error:

```
> [3/7] RUN ["/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"]:
#6 0.263 standard_init_linux.go:228: exec user process caused: exec format error
```

Here is a link to the conda.sh file: https://pastebin.com/Epu4d7Nq

I read that this might be because I am building a Linux image on Windows10...Any ideas?

Comment: I have two flags to close this question due to lack of clarity. What extra details would you like to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [RUN Syntax](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run):

> **RUN**
>
> RUN has 2 forms:
>
> - RUN  (shell form, the command is run in a shell, which by default is /bin/sh -c on Linux or cmd /S /C on Windows)
> - RUN ["executable", "param1", "param2"] (exec form)

What you choose is `exec form` which won't run in a shell, so your `/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` surely fails.

To fix it you need to change to:

```
RUN ["bash", "/opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"]
```

Or just use `shell form`:

```
RUN /opt/conda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh
```

Minimal example:

**run.sh:**

```
echo "hello"
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY run.sh /
RUN ["bash", "/run.sh"]
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 2/3 : COPY run.sh /
 ---> 8741ec438afd
Step 3/3 : RUN ["bash", "/run.sh"]
 ---> Running in 5e6754c79bc1
hello
Removing intermediate container 5e6754c79bc1
 ---> 3edd77959de4
Successfully built 3edd77959de4
Successfully tagged abc:1
```

**AND, if not use `bash`, it will show error likes next:**

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY run.sh /
RUN ["/run.sh"]
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 . --no-cache
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 065cf14a189c
Step 2/3 : COPY run.sh /
 ---> 82412a703847
Step 3/3 : RUN ["/run.sh"]
 ---> Running in 2a2b00f966c7
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"
The command '/run.sh' returned a non-zero code: 1
```